# Interpret momentum applied on a rod when holding it from one end

Tags: forces, torque, visualization, intuition

Yesterday I started wondering exactly how much more effort it takes holding a rod from one of it's edged instead of from it's centre.

Picture a rod, held by your hand from under it's centre. The force applied by your hand will be equals to the weight of the rod. This can be represented as fixed rod. Simple enough.

[image]

If you were to hold the rod from it's left end instead, moments would appear, thus making it harder to hold the rod. This situation can be represented as a rod with it's left end fixed to a wall.

[image]

For the rod to be in equilibrium net forces acting on it must sum zero. So:
$$\sum F= F + P = 0 \Rightarrow F = -P$$
$$\sum M = M_F + xP = 0 \Rightarrow M_F = -xP$$

Which means in order to hold the rod by one of it's ends your hand must provide a force equal to the weight of the rod, plus a moment equal to that applied in your hand by the CoM of the rod.

Now, imagining the effort of holding a rod by it's centre is something quite intuitive, it is just the weight of it. It is also very intuitive that the further you hold it from it's centre the harder it gets to do so, as I just showed, due to the moment you must exert on the rod. But exactly how much harder is it? How can we translate moment to force? I guess you really can't since they are different physical magnitudes, but there must be a way to represent equivalence, something along the lines of "applying this many Nm of moment feels like applying this many N of force". At the end of the day, if one were to hold the end of the rod with nothing but two fingers, the needed moment would be applied as a downwards force by the upmost of the two fingers.

[image]